# SQL Server database backup from C#, using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, backup

Please help me I am using SQL Server. I want to create a backup to my device after action EXECUTION text execution in mvc C#.

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - this is currently very vague and unclear - please add more meaningful information to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have BackUp method in HomeController, then execute the follwoing store procedure.

```
_dbcontext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, @"EXEC [dbo].[spBackUpDatabases]");
```

and spBackUpDatabases store procedure is like

```
USE [TestAppDbContext]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spBackUpDatabases]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


--  backup database TestAppDbContext to disk='D:/TestAppDb/test.bak'

 exec( 'backup database TestAppDbContext to disk = N''D:/TestAppDb/test.bak'' with format, init;' );

END
```

I think this help u.

Comment: This is very helpful , i got backup using above code, Thank a lot.